# Building a tileset incrementally, using GDAL / gdal2tiles.py

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

I have a tileset covering a local area (currently around 500km2, but growing towards 3000km2). The tileset is built from a number of ecw files with gdal2tiles.py:

```
$ gdalbuildvrt all.vrt parts/*.ecw
$ gdal2tiles.py all.vrt target
```

Each ECW file covers a 1x1km area in a grid (using epsg:25832). So they are not overlapping, but they are touching. The grid pattern is not aligned with anything in the target crs in any obvious way. The target crs is epsg:3857 (or perhaps epsg:4326).

So when calling gdal2tiles.py on any subset of ecw files, the resulting tileset will contain a number of tiles around the perimiter(s), where some fraction of the tile is transparent because its outside the extent of the input.

Later in time I want to extend the coverage of the tileset, by adding data from other ecw files to the tilearea.

The naive approach is one of the following:

- `$ gdal2tiles.py addition.ecw target`
- `$ gdal2tiles.py addition.ecw -resume target`

The result is fine for all tiles not previously created or tiles that were created but were 100% transparent all over. But for the tiles that are on the perimeter, they kind of need to be merged/patched together (the new tiles patched together with the existing tiles).

What is a good solution for creating tilesets incrementally?

**Motivation:**

Creating the entire tileset from scratch requires both a lot of time (24-72 hours). Its hard to predict what areas I need covered. If I had to download everything and be sure that every need in the reasonable future is covered, that would require a lot of downloaded data, a lot of disk space, a lot of computing time and a lot of my time :)